# Can't add JTree to JPanel of a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtree

I have two panels in my JInternalframe.I want to add Jtree to second Jpanel named topPanel.
But I cant add Jtree to topPanel.Please help me. This my piece of code:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Deck");

DefaultMutableTreeNode itemClubs = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Clubs");
addAllCard(itemClubs);
root.add(itemClubs);

DefaultMutableTreeNode itemDiamonds = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Diamonds");
addAllCard(itemDiamonds);
root.add(itemDiamonds);

DefaultMutableTreeNode itemSpades = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Spades");
addAllCard(itemSpades);
root.add(itemSpades);

DefaultMutableTreeNode itemHearts = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Hearts");
addAllCard(itemHearts);
root.add(itemHearts);
DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
tree = new JTree(treeModel);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
// scrollPane.setViewportView(tree);

scrollPane.getViewport().add(tree);

topPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

topPanel.setVisible(true);  

tree.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Don't add a component to the `JViewport`, use something more like `scrollPane.setViewportView(tree)`, but since you've already set it via the constructor, there's no need to do that either

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Try, also, `tree.expandPath(new TreePath(root))` as the root is normally collapsed by default...and not visible :P

Comment: I assume that `topPanel` has actually been added to something...that is displayable

Comment: That you're only choices to provide a runnable example...

Comment: topPanel is added to JInternalFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, works for me, there must be something you're not showing us.

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

[image: TreeExample]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class TreeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TreeTest();
    }

    public TreeTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
                JInternalFrame inFrame = new JInternalFrame("Tree", true, true, true, true);
                inFrame.add(new TestPane());
                inFrame.pack();
                inFrame.setVisible(true);
                desktopPane.add(inFrame);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(desktopPane);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Deck");
            DefaultMutableTreeNode itemClubs = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Clubs");
            root.add(itemClubs);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode itemDiamonds = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Diamonds");
            root.add(itemDiamonds);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode itemSpades = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Spades");
            root.add(itemSpades);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode itemHearts = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Hearts");
            root.add(itemHearts);
            DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
            JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);
//            tree.setRootVisible(true);
//            tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

            JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            topPanel.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
            add(topPanel);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Here where is panel topPanel.

Comment: If you really want, create a new `JPanel` `TestPane` and add it to the `TestPane`...same result

Comment: Sorry Iam not able to post my image.

Comment: I have two panels  in my design and creating panel using swing controls of netbeans and not programmatically.

Comment: Post and runnable example the demonstrates your problem until you  do that, there's nothing more that can be done